# How to append python list to a numpy matrix in fastest way?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I am writing a code to read research data which have up to billion lines. I have to read data line by line because the data have multiple blocks. Each block has headers which are different from other block headers and datasets.
I hope to read those datasets into a Numpy matrix so I can perform matrix operations. Here are essential codes.

```
    with open(datafile, "r") as dump:
        i = 0           # block line number
        line_no = 0     # total line number
        block_size = 0
        block_count = 0
        for line in dump:
            values = line.rstrip().rsplit()
            i += 1
            line_no += 1
            if i <= self.head_line_no:
                print(line)  # for test
                if self.tag_block in line or i == 1:      # 1st line of a block
                    # save block size after reading 1st block
                    if block_size == 0 and block_count == 0:
                        block_size = line_no - 1
                        i = 1               # reset block line number
                        self.box = []       # reset box constant
                        print(self.matrix)
                        self.matrix = np.zeros((0, 0), dtype="float")   # reset matrix

                    block_count += 1
                elif i == 2:
                    self.timestamp.append(values[0])
                elif i == 3 or i == 5:
                    continue
                elif i == 4:
                    if self.atom_no != 0 and self.atom_no != values[0]:
                        self.warning_message = "atom number in timestep " + self.timestamp[-1] + "is inconsistent with" + self.timestamp[-2]
                        config.ConfigureUserEnv.log(self.warning_message)
                    else:
                        pass
                    self.atom_no = values[0]
                elif i == 6 or i == 7 or i == 8:
                    self.box.append(values[0])
                    self.box.append(values[1])
                elif i == self.head_line_no:
                    values = line.rstrip().rsplit(":")
                    for j in range(1,len(values)):
                        self.column_name.append(values[j])
            else:
                if self.matrix.size != 0:
                    np_array = np.array(values)
                    self.matrix = np.append(self.matrix, np.array(np.asarray(values)), 0)     
                else:
                    np_array = np.array(values)
                    self.matrix = np.zeros((1,len(values)), dtype="float")
                    self.matrix = np.asarray(values)
        dump.close()
        print(self.matrix)       # for test
        print(self.matrix.size)  # for test
```

Original data like below:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
100
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
17587
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0.0000000000000000e+00 4.3491000000000000e+01
0.0000000000000000e+00 4.3491000000000000e+01
0.0000000000000000e+00 1.2994000000000000e+02
ITEM: ATOMS id type q xs ys zs 
59 1 1.80278 0.110598 0.129682 0.0359397 
297 1 1.14132 0.139569 0.0496654 0.00692627 
315 1 1.17041 0.0832356 0.00620818 0.00507927 
509 1 1.67165 0.0420777 0.113817 0.0313991 
590 1 1.65209 0.114966 0.0630015 0.0447129 
731 1 1.65143 0.0501253 0.13658 0.0108512 
1333 2 1.049 0.00850751 0.0526546 0.0406341 
......
```

I hope to add matrix data like below:

```
matrix = [[59 1 1.80278 0.110598 0.129682 0.0359397],
[297 1 1.14132 0.139569 0.0496654 0.00692627],
[315 1 1.17041 0.0832356 0.00620818 0.00507927],
...]
```

As mentioned above, there are very big size of datasets. I hope to use the fastest way to append array to the matrix. Any further help and advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some important point to speed up the computation:

- **Do not use `self.matrix = np.append(self.matrix, ...)` in a loop**, this is not efficient as it recreate a new growing array for each iteration (and copy the old one). This result in a *quadratic run time*. Use a pure-Python list instead with `append` and convert the list to a Numpy array in the end. This is the most *critical performance-wise point*.
- Using *`self.box.extend((values[0], values[1]))`* should be significantly faster than performing two `append`.
- Using `dtype="float"` is not very clear not very efficient, please consider using *`dtype=np.float64`* instead (that do not need to be parsed by Numpy).
- Using *`enumerate`* may be a bit faster than a manual increment in the loop.
- *Cython* may help you to speed up this program if this is not fast enough for your input file. One should keep in mind that the standard Python interpreter (CPython) is not very fast to parse complex huge files compared to compiled native programs/modules written in languages like C or C++.

Note that `values[i]` are *strings* and so `self.timestamp` and `self.box`. Aren't they supposed to be integers/floats?